# Does Android have a default notification Theme (@style)?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-theme, android-night-mode, android-dark-theme

**I would like to know if Android has a custom notification theme (@style) that we can use on our custom notifications layout.**

The reason I ask this is because I am developing a notification with a custom layout (set through .xml), and I could not find any Notification theme from Android. All I could find was some notification `TextAppearances`, which is not enough for the problem I am going through:

On some devices (Samsung mostly) that are API 28 or lower (Android <= 9), when the user activates the Dark Mode through the system, that custom notification does not follow the system color pattern (it does not adapt the background and foreground color of the notification, even though I do not set background and foreground color in any of my custom layout views).

Comment: i have exactly the same problem... anybody?